# Unable to use utf8mb4 character set with CloudSQL on AppEngine Python

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine

I have set up a CloudSQL instance that I am attempting to use with my Django app on AppEngine.  I've confirmed that the server is set to use `utf8mb4` character set via the CloudSQL console for my database:

```
utf8mb4 utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

If I connect directly with the mysql cli, I can successfully insert and read emojis.  However, if I insert the same emoji characters through the Django admin it's just inserted as "? ? ? ?".

I attempted to ensure the MySQLdb-python client is using utf8mb4 with:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
...
'OPTIONS': {
    'charset': "utf8mb4",
}
```

But this causes me to receive the following error on AppEngine:

```
(2019, "Can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: /usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/)")
```

My app.yaml is using the "latest" MySQLdb library:

```
libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"
```

Comment: Same exact problem, please if you found a solution write it here. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've tried MySQLdb (1.2.5) connecting remotely and it works fine, it leads me to believe the libmysqlclient on GAE is too old and is the real issue. I'm about to give up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just chatted with google and got everything working for our instance!

The standard way to get utf8mb4 working in Django is to specify it as DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'] in settings.py, like this:

```
'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
```

This causes an OperationalError in App Engine, on MySQLdb 1.2.4b4 / 1.2.4 / 1.2.5; which apparently means that the MySQL C client google is compiling against is missing the utf8mb4 character set.

Remove this OPTIONS setting.

The workaround is to manually call SET NAMES; edit lib/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py and add a conn.query("SET NAMES utf8mb4") line into DatabaseWrapper.get_new_connection, so it looks like this:

```
def get_new_connection(self, conn_params):
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
    conn.encoders[SafeText] = conn.encoders[six.text_type]
    conn.encoders[SafeBytes] = conn.encoders[bytes]
    conn.query("SET NAMES utf8mb4")
    return conn
```

Make sure that you also have utf8mb4 enabled on the backend.  The migration commands in the App Engine Django tutorial result in a Cloud SQL instance configured for utf8.  I needed to run these commands to enable utf8mb4 on the two tables:

```
ALTER TABLE polls_question CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
ALTER TABLE polls_choice CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```